# Getting error while capturing JSON response to CSV in python

Tags: python, json

could not able to capture all JSON results to CSV.

```
UsergroupURL = "https://" + Test + "3ds.com"
select_params = "select=title,description,owner,members,pending_members,creation_date,modification_date"
skip_value = 0
data = {}
while True:
    UsergroupsURL = UsergroupURL + f"/v1.00/usersgroup?{select_params}&top=100&skip={skip_value}"
    usergroupresponse = session.get(UsergroupsURL, data=data)
    if usergroupresponse.status_code != 200:
        Failmsg = "Failed to retrieve usergroup. Status code: " + str(usergroupresponse.status_code)
        sys.exit(Failmsg)

    results = usergroupresponse.json()
    results = json.loads(usergroupresponse.text)
    print(results)
    if not results:
        break
    
    #Print the results for this iteration
    for row in results:
        print(row)
    
    # Write the results to a CSV file
    csv_filename = f"response_{skip_value}.csv"
    with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(["title", "description", "owner", "members", "pending_members", "creation_date", "modification_date"])
        for result in results:        
            if isinstance(result, dict):
                row = [result.get("title"), result.get("description"), result.get("owner"), result.get("members"), result.get("pending_members"), result.get("creation_date"), result.get("modification_date")]
                row = result.split(',')
                #writer.writerow(row)
            else:
                print("Error: result is not a dictionary")
            #row = result.split(',')                
            row = [
                    result.get("title"), 
                    result.get("description"), 
                    result.get("owner"), 
                    result.get("members"), 
                    result.get("pending_members"), 
                    result.get("creation_date"), 
                    result.get("modification_date")
            ]
            writer.writerow(row)
 
    # Increment the skip value by 100
    skip_value += 100`
```

**output of the above code**

```
title,description,owner,members,pending_members,creation_date,modification_date
g,r,o,u,p,s
```

am expecting all json response should be captured in CSV

**My json response looks like:**

```
{
"groups": \[
    {
        "uri": "uuid:uuid1",
        "title": "ADMIN_CS",
        "description": "description1",
        "owner": "test.ferrer@abcd.com",
        "creation_date": "2021-09-10T14:42:04.443Z",
        "modification_date": "2023-03-17T13:15:22.287Z",
        "members": \[
            "member1",
            "member2",
            "member3",
        \],
        "pending_members": \[\]
    },
    {
        "uri": "uuid:uuid2",
        "title": "ADMIN_CS",
        "description": "description1",
        "owner": "test.ferrer@abcd.com",
        "creation_date": "2021-09-10T14:42:04.443Z",
        "modification_date": "2023-03-17T13:15:22.287Z",
        "members": \[
            "member1",
            "member2",
            "member3",
        \],
        "pending_members": \[\]
    },
    {
        "uri": "uuid:uuid3",
        "title": "ADMIN_CS",
        "description": "description1",
        "owner": "test.ferrer@abcd.com",
        "creation_date": "2021-09-10T14:42:04.443Z",
        "modification_date": "2023-03-17T13:15:22.287Z",
        "members": \[
            "member3",
            "member2",
            "member3",
        \],
        "pending_members": \[\]
    },
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code first? My tip as a experienced programmer, debug first, ask later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating your writing step. If all you need to do is convert the objects in the `.groups` array, then you can replace this:

```
# Write the results to a CSV file
csv_filename = f"response_{skip_value}.csv"
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["title", "description", "owner", "members", "pending_members", "creation_date", "modification_date"])
    for result in results:        
        if isinstance(result, dict):
            row = [result.get("title"), result.get("description"), result.get("owner"), result.get("members"), result.get("pending_members"), result.get("creation_date"), result.get("modification_date")]
            row = result.split(',')
            #writer.writerow(row)
        else:
            print("Error: result is not a dictionary")
        #row = result.split(',')                
        row = [
                result.get("title"), 
                result.get("description"), 
                result.get("owner"), 
                result.get("members"), 
                result.get("pending_members"), 
                result.get("creation_date"), 
                result.get("modification_date")
        ]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

with this:

```
# Write the results to a CSV file
csv_filename = f"response_{skip_value}.csv"
with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    header = ["title", "description", "owner", "members", "pending_members", "creation_date", "modification_date"]
    writer.writerow(header)
    for group in results['groups']:
        writer.writerow(group[x] for x in header)
```

This code uses [generator expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) to simplify a lot of the loops you used. I also extracted the header row into its own variable so that you can change `header` without needing to change any other code.

Comment: Michael M Now all response get appended properly, its working fine, but small problem is continuously new response CSV is creating, if the response from API 0, How to break it

Comment: @Raji I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that you want to put everything in one big CSV file instead of separate CSVs for each request?

Comment: Michael M When hitting  URL each time, only 100 data can be retrieved,So, initially, I will set the skip value to 0 and retrieve the first 100 data, then append it to a CSV file,Next, set skip = 100 and retrieve the second 100 data, then append it to another CSV. When there is no response when hitting the URL, creating a new CSV should be stopped,In my case, the CSV file is being continuously created., need to beark it.

Comment: @Raji What does a "no response" look like? Will the response have a different status code, or will the length of `groups` just be 0?

Comment: If an empty response means `groups` is empty, then try changing your `if not results:` if-statement to `if len(results['groups']) == 0:`

Comment: Michael M Its working perfectly.